# Why one sqlite query is so much slower even though they are very similar?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

>

> sqlite> .timer on
>
> ## query 1
>
> sqlite> select count(*) from alpha where Name = 'SHOUT' and Date between 20130101 and  20140101;
>
> 3783443
>
> CPU Time: user 42.067187 sys 2.098010
>
> ## query 2
>
> sqlite> select count(*) from alpha where Date between 20130101 and  20140101;
>
> 3783443
>
> CPU Time: user 0.450523 sys 0.054451
>
> ## Schema:
>
> sqlite> .schema
>   CREATE TABLE alpha (
>     Date Date,
>     Name VARCHAR(50),
>     Symbol VARCHAR(10),
>     Value FLOAT,
>     ChangeDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
>     PRIMARY KEY (Date,Name,Symbol) );
>   CREATE TABLE cusip (
>     Symbol VARCHAR(10),
>     Cusip VARCHAR(9),
>     PRIMARY KEY (Symbol) );
>
> CREATE INDEX idx_alpha_Date on alpha (Date);
>
> CREATE INDEX idx_alpha_Symbol on alpha (Symbol);
>
> CREATE INDEX idx_alpha_date_name on alpha ( Date, Name );
>
> CREATE INDEX idx_alpha_name on alpha (Name);

Answer (score 0):

Use `explain query plan` to see how the indices are used and for more details, `explain` to see how it translates to sqlite virtual machine code.

```
sqlite> explain query plan select count(*) from alpha where Name = 'SHOUT' and Date between 20130101 and 20140101;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE alpha USING INDEX idx_alpha_name (Name=?) (~5 rows)
sqlite> explain query plan select count(*) from alpha where Date between 20130101 and 20140101;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE alpha USING COVERING INDEX idx_alpha_date_name (Date>? AND Date<?) (~31250 rows)
```

In the first case, an index is used only for the `Name = 'SHOUT'` part and `Date between 20130101 and 20140101` is applied to all results in that intermediate result set, possibly taking a long time. In the latter case, the results can be obtained from an index alone, without needing to scan through an intermediate result set.

Comment: I have indices on both fields being used in the query.  Why does it not use the index to optimize both parts of the query?  Perhaps more importantly, How can I make the slower query run approximately as fast as the faster one?